# PostgreSQL - finding text values that are not valid JSON

Tags: postgresql

Casting a text value that doesn't contain valid JSON to JSON just bombs out the statement. I have no idea which row or value. How do I get this?

Fingers crossed that it doesn't involve a UDF... I really don't want to inject these into our stack. (We use Ruby Rails ActiveRecord for database migrations, and I'm almost certain UDFs will *not* be recorded into `schema.rb`.)

Comment: A function **is** the best (and probably only) solution. If your obfuscation layer doesn't allow you to use one, you should find something different.

Comment: Did you try `to_json`?

Answer (score 0):

you an check values with exception to find rows, eg:

```
t=# do
$$
declare _r record;
begin
  for _r in (with j as (select * from (values ('3'),('{"valid":true}'),('notValid') ) as son) select column1 v from j) loop
    begin
      perform _r.v::json;
      exception when others then raise info '%',concat(_r.v,' ',SQLSTATE);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  notValid 22P02
DO
t=# \e
INFO:  test3 22P02
INFO:  notValid 22P02
DO
```